# How to get the property of sonar-project.properties from the Sonar java custom rules

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

How to get the property of sonar-project.properties from the Sonar java custom rules.

I have written a class , but it return null. I am using SONARQUBE 7.0

```
public class PropertyFinder  {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertyFinder.class);

public static Configuration settings = null;

public PropertyFinder(Configuration settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
}

public static Settings getSettings() {
    return settings;
}


Also


public class JavaRulesPlugin implements Plugin {


  public static final String FILE_SUFFIXES_KEY = "sonar.java.file.suffixes";

  @Override
  public void define(Context context) {

    context.addExtension(JavaRulesDefinition.class);        
    context.addExtension(PropertyFinder.class); 
    context.addExtension(SonarJavaFileScannersFactory.class);

}

I call PropertyFinder.getSettings() from Custom rule but it returns null. 

public abstract class CustomBaseTreeVisitor extends BaseTreeVisitor implements JavaFileScanner {

    private Configuration settings = PropertyFinder.getSettings();
}
```